# How can i get permission callback in adapter

Tags: android, permissions

I have an `ArrayAdapter` where I need to pick images ...but first i need to check the permissions are granted or not...how can i get the `callback` for `OnPermissionsResult` in my adapter.

Comment: using interface (call adapter method on OnPermissionsResult)